# A trigonometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\alpha$ be a real number. I'm asked to discuss the convergence of the series 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{(kx)}}{k^\alpha}
$$
where $x \in [0,2\pi]$.

Well, I show you what I've done:

- if $\alpha \le 0$ the series cannot converge (its general term does not converge to $0$ when $k \to +\infty$) unless $x=k\pi$ for $k=0,1,2$. In other words, if $\alpha \le 0$ there is pointwise convergence only in $x=0,\pi,2\pi$.
- if $\alpha \gt 1$, I can use the Weierstrass M-test to conclude that the series is uniformly convergent hence pointwise convergent for every $x \in [0,2\pi]$. Moreover the sum is a continuous function in $[0,2\pi]$.

Would you please help me in studying what happens for $\alpha \in (0,1]$? Are there any useful criteria that I can use?

Does the series converge? And what kind of convergence is there? In case of non uniform but pointwise convergence, is the limit function continuous?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps an analysis of the $\zeta(x)$ series may help reveal some answers.

Comment: try this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test

Comment: Dirichlet's test seems a very beautiful tool! Thanks! Using Dirichlet, I have pointwise convergence for every $x \in [0,2\pi]$ also when $\alpha \in (0,1]$. What about the uniform convergence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem (at least for me) is to prove that sum of the series 
$$
f_\alpha(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k^\alpha},\quad x\in[0,2\pi]
$$
is discontinuous for $\alpha\in(0,1]$.

> **Lemma 1.** For $\alpha\in(0,1]$ we have 
>   $$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\frac{\sin(xt)}{k^\alpha}dt=
> \int\limits_{1/2}^\infty\frac{\sin(xt)}{t^\alpha}dt+\varphi(x) 
> $$
>   where $|\varphi(x)|\leq 2^{1-\alpha}$ for all $x\in[0,2\pi]$.

**Proof.** It is enough to show that difference between this sum and this integral is bounded by some constant. Now, we make estimation
$$
\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\frac{\sin(xt)}{k^\alpha}dt-
\int\limits_{1/2}^\infty\frac{\sin(xt)}{t^\alpha}dt\right|=
\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\left(\frac{\sin(xt)}{k^\alpha}-
\frac{\sin(xt)}{t^\alpha}\right)dt\right|\leq
$$
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}|\sin(xt)|\left|\frac{1}{k^\alpha}-\frac{1}{t^\alpha}\right|dt\leq
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\left|\frac{1}{k^\alpha}-\frac{1}{t^\alpha}\right|dt=
$$
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{t^\alpha}-\frac{1}{k^\alpha}\right)dt+\int\limits_{k}^{k+1/2}\left(\frac{1}{k^\alpha}-\frac{1}{t^\alpha}\right)dt\right)=
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k}\frac{1}{t^\alpha}dt-\int\limits_{k}^{k+1/2}\frac{1}{t^\alpha}dt\right)\leq
$$
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k}\frac{1}{(k-1/2)^\alpha}dt-\int\limits_{k}^{k+1/2}\frac{1}{(k+1/2)^\alpha}dt\right)\leq
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2(k-1/2)^\alpha}-\frac{1}{2(k+1/2)^\alpha}\right)=2^{\alpha-1}
$$

> **Lemma 2.** For $\alpha\in(0,1]$ we have 
>   $$ 
> \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k^\alpha}=
> \frac{x^\alpha}{2\sin(x/2)}\int\limits_{x/2}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y^\alpha}+\frac{x\varphi(x)}{2\sin(x/2)}
> $$
>   where $|\varphi(x)|\leq 2^{1-\alpha}$ for all $x\in[0,2\pi]$.

**Proof.** Note that
$$
\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\sin(xt)dt=
-\frac{1}{x}\cos(xt)\biggl|_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}=
\frac{2\sin(kx)\sin(x/2)}{x}
$$
so,
$$
\sin(kx)=\frac{x}{2\sin(x/2)}\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\sin(xt)dt
$$
Hence from lemma 1 we conclude
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k^\alpha}=
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x}{2k^\alpha\sin(x/2)}\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\sin(xt)dt=
\frac{x}{2\sin(x/2)}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int\limits_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\frac{\sin(xt)}{k^\alpha}dt=
$$
$$
\frac{x}{2\sin(x/2)}\left(\int\limits_{1/2}^\infty\frac{\sin(xt)}{t^\alpha}dt+\varphi(x) \right)
$$
Making substitution $y=tx$ we get
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k^\alpha}=
\frac{x}{2\sin(x/2)}\left(\frac{1}{x^{1-\alpha}}\int\limits_{x/2}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y^\alpha}dy+\varphi(x) \right)=
\frac{x^\alpha}{2\sin(x/2)}\int\limits_{x/2}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y^\alpha}dy+\frac{x\varphi(x)}{2\sin(x/2)}
$$

> **Corollary 3.** For $\alpha\in(0,1]$ the function $f_\alpha$ is discontinuous at $0$.

**Proof.** Obviously $f_\alpha(0)=0$. Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$, then  from fromula proved in lemma 2 we see that
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to +0}f_\alpha(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to +0}\left(\frac{x^\alpha}{2\sin(x/2)}\int\limits_{x/2}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y^\alpha}dy+\frac{x\varphi(x)}{2\sin(x/2)}\right)
$$
Since $\varphi$ is bounded then the second term is bounded while the first tends to infinity. Hence the last limit is $\lim\limits_{x\to +0}f_\alpha(x)=+\infty$.

If $\alpha=1$, then $|\varphi(x)|\leq 1$ and since 
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to+0}\frac{x}{2\sin(x/2)}=1,
$$
then 
$$
\left|\frac{x\varphi(x)}{2\sin(x/2)}\right|<\frac{\pi}{3}
$$
for some $\delta_1>0$ and $x\in(0,\delta_1)$. Since
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to+0}\frac{x}{2\sin(x/2)}\int\limits_{x/2}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y}dy=
\int\limits_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y}dy=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
then
$$
\frac{x}{2\sin(x/2)}\int\limits_{x/2}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y}dy>\frac{2\pi}{5}
$$
for some $\delta_2>0$ and all $x\in(0,\delta_2)$. Thus for all $x\in(0,\min(\delta_1,\delta_2))$ we see that
$$
f_\alpha(x)=\frac{x^\alpha}{2\sin(x/2)}\int\limits_{x/2}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y^\alpha}dy+\frac{x\varphi(x)}{2\sin(x/2)}>\frac{2\pi}{5}-\frac{\pi}{3}>0
$$

In both cases $\lim\limits_{x\to+0}f_\alpha(x)\neq 0$. hence $f_\alpha$ is discontinuous at $0$.

> **Corollary 4.** For $\alpha\in(0,1]$ the series 
>   $$
> \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k^\alpha}
> $$
>   doesn't converges uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$.

**Proof.** Assume that this series converges uniformly. Since this series is the sum of continuous functions and its converges uniformly, then its sum $f_\alpha$ must be continuous function on $[0,2\pi]$. This contradicts corallary 3, hence our series is not uniformly convergent on $[0,2\pi]$.

> **Remark 5.** Despite the above, this series converges uniformly on $[\delta,2\pi-\delta]$ for all $\delta\in(0,\pi]$. You can use [Dirichlet test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) to prove this.

Comment: Great, your proof is beautiful! Thanks! I have still one more question: what about the continuity of the limit function (for $\alpha \in (0,1]$)?

Comment: @Romeo, see edits to my answer.

Comment: Your proof doesn't work when $\alpha=1$: the RHS of Lemma 2 remains bounded.

Comment: @GenericHuman, I've edit my answer. Now it covers both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \sin(kx) = \dfrac{\sin(Nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)} \sin \left( \left(\dfrac{N+1}2 \right)x\right)$$ Hence, for each given $x$, the sum is bounded by $\dfrac1{\sin(x/2)}$.

Hence by generalized alternating series test (also known as [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)) the sum converges.

Comment: I thank you all for your kind replies. The fact that the bound depends on $x$ suggests me that the convergence is not uniform when $\alpha \in (0,1]$... Am I right? How can I prove this formally?

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier proof that $f_\alpha$ is discontinuous at 0.

Let $x=\pi/n$ for some even $n$. Then for $1\le i\le n$, group terms $a_{2nk+i}$ and $a_{2nk+i+n}$ together:
$$\frac{\sin (2nk+i)x}{(2nk+i)^\alpha}+\frac{\sin (2nk+i+n)x}{(2nk+i+n)^\alpha}\ge\frac{n\alpha}{(2nk+i)(2nk+i+n)^\alpha}\sin \frac{i\pi}{n} \ge 0$$
We need only use $k=0$ and $i\le n/2$ for the lower bound:
$$\begin{align}
f_\alpha(x)\ge&\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{n}{i(i+n)^\alpha}\sin \frac{i\pi}{n}\\
\ge&\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{2}{(i+n)^\alpha}\qquad{\text{($\sin t\ge 2/\pi\cdot t$)}}\\
\ge&2\alpha\log\frac{3n/2+1}{n+1}\\
\rightarrow&2\alpha\log 3/2
\end{align}$$
So $f_\alpha$ is bounded from below by a positive number as $x\rightarrow 0$, for all $\alpha\in(0,1]$. Because $f_\alpha(0)=0$, the convergence cannot be uniform around 0.

Comment: Right, I was bounding $\cos t$ instead of $\sin t$. Thanks! Note that actually $f_1(x)=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$.

Comment: It seems that your proof shows that $\lim\limits_{x\to+0} f_1(x)=+\infty$. But it is known that $f_1(x)=(\pi-x)/2$ for $x\in(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Ok, now no question left :)